# I am Not Able to connect .NET MAUI Project with MS SQL Connection

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

I am Using MS SQL in .NET Maui Project and I am not able to get connected . the problem is that when i am using System.data.Sqlclient it is not showing me mssqlconnection object so I tried with Microsoft.data.mssqlclient and this time it is giving error "Connection was established but there is problem during pre login handshake " can you please give me any suggestion ,

```
string myconnect = "Data Source =hostname\\servername; " +
       "Initial catalog =dbase;User ID=user;Password=pass;";  
    SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection (myconnect);
    MyConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand();
    mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    mycmd.CommandText = "select * from logins where UserName =@user and PassWord=@pass ";
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", txtUser.Text);
    mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", txtPass.Text);
    mycmd.Connection = MyConnection;
    SqlDataReader myread = mycmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (myread.Read())
    {
        DisplayAlert("TEST", "PasswordOK", "Press");
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("TEST", "Password Is Bad", "Press");
    }
```

Comment: it is a very, very bad idea to connect directly from a mobile client to a database server

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=there+is+problem+during+pre+login+handshake+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: one small suggestion, please use `using` and don't use `select *` and define your connection string in some config file

Comment: You can try to use the sqlite instead of the MySql.

Comment: Put your data access behind a web service or headless function. In Azure, web app or function app should handle the data access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Maui how to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778682/net-maui-how-to-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package from `NuGet` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`.

[See this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75640341/3392605).