# How to connect SQL Server with .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, maui

How to connect SQL Server with .NET MAUI?

I tried to import ADO.NET, but it shows an error

> The project's target framework does not contain Entity Framework runtime assembles

Comment: It is a really bad idea to connect directly to a db server from a mobile app

Comment: **Googling that error message,** I see [Adding ADO.Net Entity Framework gives ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70580916/199364). Try answer there. Or look at other links listed when google that error message.

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve, but unfortunately It's all not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should configure app constants. Configuration data, such as database filename and path, can be stored as constants in your app.

Then, you can create a database access class, and this is the solution for connecting DAL to .NET Maui. A database wrapper class abstracts the data access layer from the rest of the app. This class centralizes query logic and simplifies the management of database initialization, making it easier to refactor or expand data operations as the app grows. The SQLite.NET library provides a simple Object Relational Map (ORM) that allows you to store and retrieve objects without writing SQL statements.

Finally, you can access data smoothly. You can register your pages and the database access class as services on the IServiceCollection object, in MauiProgram.cs, with the AddSingleton and AddTransient methods.

For more details about these steps, you can refer to the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-7.0.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not a good idea to directly connect your application directly to the database. Instead, you should create an abstraction layer in the middle, as Data Access Layer (DAL) that allows you to do the infrastructure and database work, without directly affecting the application. See more about DAL: [Microsoft Learn — Creating a Data Access Layer (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs)

If you still wish to go ahead and access directly. You will need to do something along the lines of the following:

```cs
public void ConnectToDatabase()
{
    // Replace with your connection string
    string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";

    // Create a new connection to the database
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    // Open the connection
    connection.Open();

    // Do some work with the connection
    // ...

    // Close the connection
    connection.Close();
}
```

Once again, though, not the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for applying. I know how to create a DAL now , but I want to know how to connect this DAL with .Net Maui. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following package from NuGet and use it as same as System.Data.SqlClient

**Microsoft.Data.SqlClient**

Example:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlconnection;
sqlconnection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(StrConn);

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, sqlconnection);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Tested on Android and Windows .NET MAUI